# How to make a selector in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, selector, android-drawable

While taking a course, I was instructed to make an xml selector for a Button. The course said to make a new Android xml in Eclipse, but i am using Android Studio.

Also when I custom write the code it gives me an error. It says "element selector must be declared".

[image: as you can see selector is an error]

Got code from here: [Android: How to Make A Drawable Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624609/android-how-to-make-a-drawable-selector).

Does anyone know how to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: Is that file of yours under **res/drawable/** folder?

Comment: Where does it give you the error "element selector must be declared"? Can you put it in a screenshot? The XML is correct (though the states are incorrect given the naming of the drawable).

Comment: yes it is, and that is a direct quote from mousing over the selector word

Comment: Can you please check again that your file is not under **res/values/** folder, but in **res/drawable/** folder where it should be! I have checked, and **values** folder, gives that exact error.

Comment: yah, messed up. but do you know how to add one within the GUI?

Comment: Just right click the **res/drawable/** folder **->** New **->** Drawable resource file

Comment: @Marko what is the status of anim or anim-v21 folders? Why doesn't it work in anim folder?

Comment: @SudhirKhanger I guess it is because the Android framework expects you to put certain types of things into their designated folder (drawables, selectors, vector images into *drawable* folder, strings, dimensions, integers into *values* folder, etc..). Anim folder doesn't have access for instance to <selector> tag mentioned above, but has access to it's own set of tags (like <set>, <animator>, <objectAnimator>,...). My guess is for reasons like, optimization in loading resources, etc..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Though it is already answered in the comment,
[image]

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there will be no drawable folder when establish a new Android Project in Android Studio likes Eclipse does. Right click on res folder--> New--> Android Resource Directory--> resource type--> drawable, and now you get a drawable folder, and then, you can add your new drawable resource file, selector, shape and .etc