# Animated Selector showing "Element selector must be declared"

Tags: android-studio, android-animation

I am trying to get a FAB to elevate when pressed.
This app is from a course on material design.
The app works, the button presses and ripples but does not elevate.
The selector tag is giving an error.
I've read the post about it needing to be in the drawable folder [how to make selector in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27734020) but it doesn't work in this case.

[anim.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8yvI.png)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was renaming the folder to `animator` instead of `anim`. Hovering over the error showed that that the folder should be named that. The error went away after right clicking on the folder and selecting refactor and thereby renaming the folder (`anim`) on Android Studio.