# How to set color for both text and icon of a tab in TabLayout when it gets focus

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-tabs

Here is my activity_custom_view_icon_text_tabs.xml layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Here is my code for activity_custom_view_icon_text_tabs.xml : http://pastebin.com/raw/h0AN6Mtj

custom_tab.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"
android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```

Comment: you can use drawable selector on textview, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624609/android-how-to-make-a-drawable-selector

Comment: use this I have to have both selected and unselected icons in drawable, is there any way else ?

Comment: this is a best way. or you can manipulate custom view on tabselection.

Comment: but text color of selected tab isn't changed, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: please have a look into my answer. @Lukie Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i run this code in my example and it is working fine.

you need to make some changes describribed in following example.

for tab selector background under *res/drawable/background_selector.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/tabcolor" />
</selector>
```

and for text selector color under *res/color/background_text_selector.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
</selector>
```

and your textview is something like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/background_text_selector">
</TextView>
```

references took from for color selector:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

and for drawable selector:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

from this links.