# event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is not true when setOnTouchListener returns false

Tags: android

I need to implement onItemLongPressListener as well as onTouchListener.They don't work together so I have to return false from ontouch listner in other for item long press listener to get triggered as well.

I need the image button to change when I touch the imageButton but since my on touch listener is returning false the image stays on the pressed down state.

How can I make it change the button image when I am no longer touching the button?

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIdsPressed[position]);
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                    }
                    recordAudio.startPlaying(position);

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question, do you simply want to change the image when `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`?

Comment: @sam yes i want the image to change when the user is no longer touching the button. but since i am forced to return "false" on the ontouch, it doesnt know that the button is released

Comment: For changing image use selector as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185930/how-to-highlight-imageview-when-focused-or-clicked . Fire your method recordAudio.startPlaying(position) you can in OnClickListener.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a GestureDetector, like [SimpleOnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html), to make the distinction between:

- [`onDown()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onDown%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), similar to `ACTION_DOWN`
- [`onSingleTapConfirmed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onSingleTapConfirmed%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) or `onSingleTapUp()`, similar to `ACTION_UP`
- [`onLongPress()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onLongPress%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) for your long press event

Answer (score 2):

I just finished doing this for my project, partly based off of you existing code (thanks for that by the way). The way I did it was instead of the "else" I did an "else if" as shown below.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        touching = false;
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        touching = true;
    }

    touch_x = event.getX();
    touch_y = event.getY();

    return true;
}
```

The touching boolean is used further on in the rendering thread.

Comment: How would that really make a difference?